# Kanban Board With Stacked Lists

Tags: methodology

Does the definition of a Kanban board permit stacked lists? In other words, can an individual column contain multiple lists (rows). If not, is there another design similar to a Kanban board that does permit this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you check out the Jira Kanban board, you'll see a stacked list where the tasks stacked on the board are consolidated based on the epics
[image]

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These are typically called **Kanban Swimlanes**.

Swimlanes are used to categorize tasks so users can more easily find the task they are looking for:

- by customer or project
- by team
- by priority (sometimes called "classes of service"). Example: the "expedite" swimlane in the screenshot by Siddarth Maran.